# access plyr id variables within functions

Tags: r, plyr

I regulary have the problem that I need to access the actual id variable when using `d*ply` or `l*ply`. A simple (yet nonsense) example would be:

```
df1 <- data.frame( p = c("a", "a", "b", "b"), q = 1:4 )
df2 <- data.frame( m = c("a", "b" ), n = 1:2 )

d_ply( df1, "p", function(x){
 actualId <- unique( x$p )
 print( mean(x$q)^df2[ df2$m == actualId, "n" ] )
})
```

So in case of `d*ply` functions I can help myself with `unique( x$p )`. But when it comes to `l*ply`, I have no idea how to access the name of the according list element.

```
l_ply( list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3), function(x){
  print( <missing code> )
})
# desired output
[1] "a"
[1] "b"
[1] "c"
```

Any suggestions? Anything I am ignoring?

Comment: @juba Well, why not? I know that there are a lot possibilities to avoid this problem from the beginning. E.g. using for-loops from the beginning, merging data.frames, bringing data into another structure. But my question was, is there a possibility if I want do it that way?

Comment: What I mean is, the goal of `l*ply` is to apply a function to each element of a list in turn, and then aggregate and send back the results. So you shouldn't really need to know the name of the element inside your function. But I may miss something important :)

Comment: @juba this is how I understood it as well and maybe I am just abusing `l*ply` for purposes where a for-loop or `lapply` would be more appropriate. If this is the case I'll accept it :-)

Comment: @Beasterfield you might want to read my take on this problem at https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/functionals (search for "Looping patterns")

Comment: @hadley It is always revealing to read through the devtools wiki :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way I've gotten around this is to loop over the index (names) and do the subsetting within the function.

```
l <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
l_ply(names(l), function(x){
  print(x)
  myl <- l[[x]]
  print(myl)
})
```

`myl` will then be the same as

```
l_ply(l, function(myl) {
  print(myl)
})
```

Comment: Actually, this is not the answer to my question, but I assume the best solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one idea.

```
l_ply( list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3), function(x){
     print(eval(substitute(names(.data)[i], parent.frame())))
})
# [1] "a"
# [1] "b"
# [1] "c"
```

(Have a look at the final code block of `l_ply` to see where I got the names `.data` and `i`.)

Comment: Or you could just poke my eyes out with a stick :P

Comment: this is basically what I was looking for, although I was hoping that there is something shorter. Plus, looking at the code I can see, that this obviously works only for `l_ply` but not for `llply`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there's a way to do that, because the only argument to your anonymous function is the list element value, without its name :

```
l_ply( list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3), function(x){
  print(class(x))
})
[1] "numeric"
[1] "numeric"
[1] "numeric"
```

But if you get back the results of your command as a list or a data frame, the names are preserved for you to use later :

```
llply( list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3), function(x){
  x
})
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 2

$c
[1] 3
```

Aside from Josh solution, you can also pass both names and values of your list elements to a function with `mapply` or `m*ply` :

```
d <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
myfunc <- function(value, name) {
  print(as.character(name))
  print(value)
}
mapply(myfunc, d, names(d))
m_ply(data.frame(value=unlist(d), name=names(d)), myfunc)
```